# Qual a forma certa de pegar valores com / ou caracteres especiais usando jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho uma função jquery em uma view, que pega a data em um campo do tipo text. O problema é que a minha função jquery .val() não pega o valor após as barras que separam as datas.

Por exemplo 12/06/2013 ele só pega o 12, desconsidera a barra e o que vem depois.

```
    $(function() {
       $('table.prospects > tbody > tr').click(function() {
          getTicketData($(this).attr('data-ticket-id'), $('#select option:selected').val(), $('#is_active option:selected').val(), $('#data1').val(), $('#data2').text());
       });

    })
```

Qual a forma certa de pegar valores com / ou caracteres especiais usando jQuery?

Comment: tentou converter para string antes o valor do input ? ex.: toString ou coisa do tipo

Comment: Tem certeza que é esse o problema? Olhe [aqui seu problema funcionando](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldgpwz02/), acho que há algo obscuro em seu código que está escondendo o real problema.

Comment: Tens algum mask no input? qual é o input e qual é o HTML dele?

Comment: Tem como postar o HTML também?